# Cassandra COPY complains with "the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900"

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am trying to export data from a table by using the COPY-command.

```
COPY my_table to 'my_Export.csv';
```

I have timestamps dating back before the year 1900. Now cqlsh tells me that strftime() does not support that.

> the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900

Is there a workaround? Googling the error-message just yields a lot of python-related results...

**Edit_1:**
 It seems that cqlsh uses thrift, which uses python 2 and is incompatible with python 3. In python 2 there is this limit concerning the year 1900. omg.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of cqlsh will use 9042 (cql native transport) instead of 9160 (thrift), but I'm not positive that will necessarily solve the issue (and I don't have time to test it out).

The fastest solution is probably to write a trivial exporter using a programming language/driver of your choice.